# SQL Server query to see what changed from month to month

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling with developing a query to compare changes in a single table from month to month, example data -

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+    
| TaxGroupDetails                                           |
+-----------+--+----------+--+-----------+--+---------------+  
| Tax Group |  | Tax Type |  |  Geocode  |  | EffectiveDate |  
+-----------+--+----------+--+-----------+--+---------------+  
|      2001 |  | 1D       |  | 440011111 |  |       1120531 |  
|      2001 |  | X1       |  | 440011111 |  |       1120531 |  
|      2001 |  | D3       |  | 440011111 |  |       1120531 |  
|      2001 |  | DGH      |  | 440011111 |  |       1120531 |  
|      2001 |  | 1D       |  | 440011111 |  |       1130101 |  
|      2001 |  | X1       |  | 440011111 |  |       1130101 |  
|      2001 |  | D3       |  | 440011111 |  |       1130101 |  
|      2001 |  | 1D       |  | 440011111 |  |       1140201 |  
|      2001 |  | X1       |  | 440011111 |  |       1140201 |  
|      2001 |  | D3       |  | 440011111 |  |       1140201 |  
|      2001 |  | Z9       |  | 440011111 |  |       1140201 |  
+-----------+--+----------+--+-----------+--+---------------+
```

I want to see the changes in the table, what was added or removed from a taxgroup, between the top two effective dates.

The results I am trying to obtain based on the sample data would be Z9 (added) if I was running the query in February (1140201) of this year.

If I was running the query in January (1130101) of last year I would expect to see DGH (removed)

I would expect two seperate queries, one to show what was added and another to show what was removed.

I have tried multiple avenues to come up with these two queries but cant seem to obtain the correct results.  Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: 1140201 = February? What is the leading 1 for? Why isn't EffectiveDate a DATE column?

Comment: sorry the formatting is a mess in my example - legacy system stores dates that way, a number column in SQL Server not a true date field.

Comment: Formatting looks ok, I've edited out your formatting question. The trick is four spaces at the start of the line to make it format as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT
        Current.TaxGroup,
        Current.TaxType,
        Current.GeoCode,
        'Added'
  FROM
        TaxGroupDetails AS Current
  WHERE
        Current.EffectiveDate = @CurrentPeriod AND
        NOT EXISTS
        (
           SELECT *
           FROM TaxGroupDetails As Previous
           WHERE 
                 Previous.EffectiveDate = @PreviousPeriod
                 Current.TaxGroup = Previous.TaxGroup and
                 Current.TaxType = Previous.TaxType and 
                 Current.GeoCode = Previous.GeoCode
        )

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
        Current.TaxGroup,
        Current.TaxType,
        Current.GeoCode,
        'Added'
  FROM
        TaxGroupDetails AS Previous
  WHERE
        Previous.EffectiveDate = @PreviousPeriod AND

        NOT EXISTS
        (
           SELECT *
           FROM TaxGroupDetails As Current
           WHERE 
                 Current.EffectiveDate = @CurrentPeriod
                 Current.TaxGroup = Previous.TaxGroup and
                 Current.TaxType = Previous.TaxType and 
                 Current.GeoCode = Previous.GeoCode
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The set-based solution: take the difference between the whole table and the whole table with all dates projected forward by one time interval.  That will eliminate all rows except the ones with "new" codes.

```
SELECT
  [TaxGroup],
  [Tax Type],
  [EffectiveDate] 
FROM TaxGroupDetails t
EXCEPT
SELECT
  [TaxGroup],
  [Tax Type],
  ( SELECT MIN([EffectiveDate])
    FROM TaxGroupDetails
    WHERE [EffectiveDate] > t.[EffectiveDate]
      AND [TaxGroup] = t.[TaxGroup]
  )
FROM TaxGroupDetails t
```

To see what got deleted, project backwards instead.  Change the subquery to:

```
    SELECT MAX([EffectiveDate])
    FROM TaxGroupDetails
    WHERE [EffectiveDate] < t.[EffectiveDate]
      AND [TaxGroup] = t.[TaxGroup]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say you need two queries, one to select each of the two groups of data you want to compare.

```
SELECT [Tax Group], [Tax Type], [Geocode], [EffectiveDate] 
FROM TaxGroupDetails 
WHERE EffectiveDate = 1120531 

SELECT [Tax Group], [Tax Type], [Geocode], [EffectiveDate] 
FROM TaxGroupDetails 
WHERE EffectiveDate = 1140201
```

You then need to join these two together using some form of key, the combination of tax group and tax type seems sensible here.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [Tax Group], [Tax Type], [Geocode], [EffectiveDate] 
    FROM TaxGroupDetails 
    WHERE EffectiveDate = 1120531 
) AS FirstGroup

FULL OUTER JOIN    

(
    SELECT [Tax Group], [Tax Type], [Geocode], [EffectiveDate] 
    FROM TaxGroupDetails 
    WHERE EffectiveDate = 1140201 
) AS SecondGroup

ON FirstGroup.[Tax Group] = SecondGroup.[Tax Group] 
AND FirstGroup.[Tax Type] = SecondGroup.[Tax Type]
```

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` here tells SQL to include the remaining row when the other doesn't exist.

Finally let's tidy up and order the columns and not use a *:

```
SELECT COALESCE(FirstGroup.[Tax Group], SecondGroup.[Tax Group]), 
    COALESCE(FirstGroup.[Tax Type], SecondGroup.[Tax Type]),
    FirstGroup.Geocode, SecondGroup.Geocode,
    FirstGroup.EffectiveDate, SecondGroup.EffectiveDate
FROM
.
.
.
```

COALESCE removes the NULLs from the first matched columns and as we are saying these muct be equal there is no point showing both copies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL2012:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [TaxGroup], [Tax Type] ORDER BY [EffectiveDate] ASC) rownum
  FROM [TaxGroup]
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE rownum = 1
  AND [EffectiveDate] = @Date
```

To get the other query, change ASC to DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try this / you could start from this [partial] solution:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    [Tax Group] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [Tax Type] VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    [Geocode] INT NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT @MyTable
          SELECT 2001, '1D ', 440011111, 1120531
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'X1 ', 440011111, 1120531
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'D3 ', 440011111, 1120531
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'DGH', 440011111, 1120531
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, '1D ', 440011111, 1130101
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'X1 ', 440011111, 1130101
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'D3 ', 440011111, 1130101
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, '1D ', 440011111, 1140201
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'X1 ', 440011111, 1140201
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'D3 ', 440011111, 1140201
UNION ALL SELECT 2001, 'Z9 ', 440011111, 1140201;

DECLARE @Results TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Rnk INT NOT NULL,
    EffectiveYear SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (Rnk, EffectiveYear)
);
INSERT @Results
SELECT  x.ID, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x.[Tax Group], x.[Tax Type], x.[Geocode]) AS Rnk,
        x.EffectiveDate / 10000 AS EffectiveYear
FROM    @MyTable x;

SELECT  
        crt.*,
        prev.*,
        CASE 
            WHEN crt.ID IS NOT NULL AND prev.ID IS NOT NULL THEN '-' -- No change
            WHEN crt.ID IS NULL AND prev.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'D' -- Deleted
            WHEN crt.ID IS NOT NULL AND prev.ID IS NULL THEN 'I' -- Inserted
        END AS RowStatus
FROM    @Results crt FULL OUTER JOIN @Results prev ON crt.Rnk = prev.Rnk
AND     crt.EffectiveYear - 1 = prev.EffectiveYear
ORDER BY ISNULL(crt.EffectiveYear - 1, prev.EffectiveYear), crt.Rnk;
```

Sample output:

```
---- ---- ------------- ---- ---- ------------- 
|     Current data    | |    Previous data    |  
---- ---- ------------- ---- ---- ------------- ---------
ID   Rnk  EffectiveYear ID   Rnk  EffectiveYear RowStatus
---- ---- ------------- ---- ---- ------------- ---------
1    1    112           NULL NULL NULL          I -- Current vs. previous: current row hasn't a previous row
3    2    112           NULL NULL NULL          I -- the same thing
4    3    112           NULL NULL NULL          I -- the same thing
2    4    112           NULL NULL NULL          I -- the same thing
NULL NULL NULL          4    3    112           D <-- Deleted: ID 4 = 'DGH'
5    1    113           1    1    112           - -- there is no change 
7    2    113           3    2    112           -
6    4    113           2    4    112           -
8    1    114           5    1    113           -
10   2    114           7    2    113           -
9    4    114           6    4    113           -
11   5    114           NULL NULL NULL          I <-- Inserted: ID 11 = 'Z9'
NULL NULL NULL          8    1    114           D 
NULL NULL NULL          10   2    114           D
NULL NULL NULL          9    4    114           D
NULL NULL NULL          11   5    114           D
```

Note: I assume that there are no duplicated rows (`x.[Tax Group], x.[Tax Type], x.[Geocode]`) within a year.